# mongodb slow query with $near and other condition

Tags: mongodb, indexing, 2d, geospatial

I have a mongodb collection named `rooms`, and it has a 2d index for field `location`. I've queried like this:

```
db.rooms.find( { "location" : { "$near" : { "latitude" : 37.3356135, "longitude" : 127.12383030000001 } }, "status": "open", "updated" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2014-06-03T15:34:22.213Z") }}).explain()
```

The result:

```
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 7,
    "nscannedObjects" : 143247,
    "nscanned" : 143247,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 143247,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 143247,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1457,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "ip-10-162-39-56:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Sometimes it takes more than 2000ms.  But if I remove the `$gt` condition for `updated` field, the query is fast, about 5~30ms.

```
> db.rooms.find( { "location" : { "$near" : { "latitude" : 37.3356135, "longitude" : 127.12383030000001 } }, "status": "open"}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1635,
    "nscanned" : 2400,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1635,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2400,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 22,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "ip-10-162-39-56:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

I've tried compound index for `{location:"2d", updated: -1}` but it didn't work. How can I make this query faster?

Comment: How much time do each of these queries take? Don't answer it in the comment, just add this info to your question by editing it.